# Google Webmaster Tools gives "404 not found" although page exists

Tags: indexing, google-search-console

My [website](http://rifflex.dot.com) is submitted to Google, but when I search for "rifflex", I don't get the homepage. I just get all the other pages of the website.

When I go to Webmaster Tools, I see in the "crawl errors" section that the homepage is giving a `404 not found` error. However, when I visit it normally, it exists and gives no errors. When I try the "Fetch as Googlebot" tool, it also doesn't give an error.

Answer (score 0):

A few questions you have to ask yourself:

- Do you do any kind of user agent
  redirection to mobile sites?
- Are you
  using any content management system?
- Have you entered anything in
  Robots.txt?
- Do you use meta tag's
  (robots)?

Check out the [IIS Search Engine Optimization Toolkit](http://www.iis.net/download/seotoolkit).  You can use it to perform easily a full analysis of your website.  Installation is very easy using the [Web Platform Installer](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9695987).

If you have still problems, you can ask your question too on the [Google Webmaster forums](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters?hl=en)